# How to check [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] in iOS development device with Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, plist, xcode9.3

In Xcode 9.3 and iOS simulators, `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` store the values at:

> /Users/{User Name}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{Device
>   GUID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{application
>   GUID}/Library/Preferences/{bundle identifier}.plist

where I could open the .plist file easily and look into the values.

But, how could I check these values when the app is running in a **development device**? Is it possible to check these values in a developed device like as simulators?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to open the PList directly instead of just using `NSUserDefaults`? If you just need to see what's stored, using `dictionaryRepresentation()` would give you everything: `for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() { print("\(key) = \(value)") }`

Comment: @Krunal Yes, this solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access it directly. Apple does not allow, an access to such kind of data (and/or files) of iOS application (for any external sources) from device.

Only application developer can access it programatically. (There are some software available in market, which can open/access files from IPA using Jail-broken devices.)

Refer this Apple document: [iOS Security - File Data Protection](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf). (There is no direct answer to your question but complete details about file and data security, in this doc.)

But if you are a developer of this app then you can find it from `AppData Preferences`.

Follow these steps to find it:

1. Open `Device and Simulator` window (Xcode (Menu) >> Window >> Devices and Simulators).
2. Select your iOS device from a list of connected devices.
3. Select an apps from a list of Installed Apps.
4. Click on application `Settings` icon
5. Select `Download Container`, that will prompt you to save you file.
6. Save your file (file extension - .xcappdata)

[image]

7. Right click on file and select `Show Package Contents`

[image]

8. A finder window will show a path to `AppData` of file.
9. Go to: `AppData >> Library >> Preferences >> <file>.plist`
10. Bingo: This is what you are looking for. `UserDefault` storage file. Open it and check your data.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this answer is incorrect - at least when it comes to an app your are developing.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me for my real development device. I was able to read the UserDefaults file using Xcode 11.4.1.

Comment: confirmed, this worked for viewing UserDefaults file downloaded from actual device. Crazy how many steps it requires just to view a snapshot.